# Apple Photos removed 10 people from my previous list after migration to Catalina

Tags: time-machine, photos, catalina, migration

I just migrated to Cataline, and Photos started reanalysing my 60k+ photos again. At first, pics were still in the right People's album, except that it was an association without a Tag, ie the person was tagged as "Unknown" but the pic was still showing up under the right name.

Yet, now the analysis is finished, I can see that 10 people / 632 have been removed from the list, and I really can't tell who!!

Also, I went to my TimeMachine and tried to locate the database file that is usually inside the package of the photo library, but I realized that these files are not there. Not in the backed-up pre-Catalina library nor in the backed-up Catalina library. But I can see the database file in the current library.

Is there a way to retrieve this database file, so as to at least know which person are now missing (I know SQL, but I need a file to be able to do something ;) )